# How can I change which monitor is used when centering the pointer with SmartNAV?

Tags: windows, smartnav

By default, centering with SmartNAV move the mouse pointer to the center of the primary monitor. How can I change which monitor is used when centering the pointer with SmartNAV?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cannot change which monitor is used when centering the pointer with SmartNAV: centering with SmartNAV will always move the mouse pointer to the center of the primary monitor.